# Can't add new scheduler policy

Tags: linux-kernel, patch, scheduler

I'm patching the kernel 2.6.24 to introduce a new scheduling policy, following this article: http://www.eetimes.com/design/embedded/4204929/Real-Time-Linux-Scheduling-Part-1
The patching and rebuilding process goes fine but after the reboot the system seems like hasn't been patched at all. To be more specific part of the code of /include/linux/sched.h is:

```
...
#define SCHED_NORMAL        0
#define SCHED_FIFO      1
#define SCHED_RR        2
#define SCHED_BATCH     3
/* SCHED_ISO: reserved but not implemented yet */
#define SCHED_IDLE      5
#define SCHED_CASIO     6
...
```

but after the reboot the /usr/include/bits/sched.h looks like

```
...
#define SCHED_OTHER 0
#define SCHED_FIFO  1
#define SCHED_RR    2
#ifdef __USE_GNU
# define SCHED_BATCH    3
#endif
...
```

What could be the problem?
I'm using Ubuntu 8.04 with a core duo t7300

Thanks,
Stefano

Comment: What did you do that would have caused /usr/include/bits/sched.h to get updated? There's nothing automatic that updates this file, it's part of libc not the kernel sources.

Comment: The file /include/linux/sched.h has been modified by the patch and I thought that after the rebuilding process this changes would have changed the /usr/include/bits/sched.h  In the end I can simplify the question: where can I see the added policy, which file, after the rebuild, should contain the "#define SCHED_CASIO"?

Comment: The include file in the kernel tree is totally separate to the include file in /usr/include. Nothing magically keeps them in sync and often they're subtly different for various reasons. You can always `#include` the one from the patched kernel tree directly in your application and skip the one in /usr/include if you want to.